# How to use the data input in Preference screen? (android honeycomb)

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb

In my app, I have used the two-pane preference screen as given in the API Demo. Now, in edit text preference, I have an option to login into Picasa. After the user inputs his username and password, how do I link that data to my activity? How can I get that data and write it in the preference file?

Answer (score 0):

```
    final EditText userNameTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginfield_username);
    final EditText passwordTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginfield_password);
    String userName = usernameTextBox.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordTextBox.getText().toString();
```

Comment: but how to handle the default buttons? (OK, CANCEL) do i need to create my own layout?